# How device connect to bundle on local host of computer in ReactNative App

Tags: react-native

How does the connection in the RN app happen between the device that runs the Native app and the bundle that is in the Metro on the computer?

I am familiar with the option that changes the bundle location when opening the RN settings pop-up

And it is clear to me that we connect via a WIFI connection to the server

What I do not understand is how the device can connect to the metro with a cable to the localHost (0.0.0.0) IP of the computer when it is actually a **separate device**